# AngularJS Toggle Dropdown Menu

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to toggle a menu item using AngularJS.  I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong because the following is not working.

```
<div ng-controller="firstController as firstCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Menu" ng-click="firstCtrl.toggle(firstCtrl.navOpen)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <ul ng-show="firstCtrl.navOpen" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>


    <p>{{firstCtrl.test1}}</p>
    <div ng-controller="secondController as secondCtrl">
        <p>{{secondCtrl.test1}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I have the following app.js file.  I am using a nested controller to learn the concept.

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("PHPAngularJSDemo", []);

app.controller("firstController", function () {
    this.test1 = "Sanjay1";
    this.navOpen = false;

    var toggle = function (navOpen) {
        if (navOpen === false) {
            navOpen = true;
        } else
            navOpen = false;
    };

});

//nested controller
app.controller("secondController", function () {
    this.test1 = "Sanjay2";
});
```

}());

I have created a plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/xJ3uDK5Mk8xEZY15Odmt?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you pass `firstCtrl.navOpen` by value to `toggle()` and then manipulate the new variable `navOpen` inside the function, but it never gets assigned back to the `firstCtrl.navOpen` that the view is using.

Check out the documentation for [functions on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), which states:

> Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions by value; the value is passed to the function, but if the function changes the value of the parameter, this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function.

In your case the parameter is a boolean, which is also primitive, and thus passed by value.

You could get your example to work as expected without calling a function at all by changing the `<button>` element:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Menu" type="button" ng-click="firstCtrl.navOpen = !firstCtrl.navOpen">
```

**edit:**
I also just noticed that the function toggle is also never getting called in your example because it is not a property of `firstController`.  In order to use a function as you have in your example, it would need to be defined as a member of `this` like so:

```
this.toggle = function () {
    this.navOpen = !this.navOpen;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Your solution is more elegant anyway.  I was playing around a bit as I learn by doing.  Is there a way to pass by reference into a function?  What if I wanted to manipulate "this.test1" inside the function, can that be done?

Comment: Again, thank you.  I understand the first valuable point of passing by value not reference and now you have helped me understand how I was not doing it right in the function call.  I had tried the "this.toggle" before but I was still trying to pass a variable by reference.  With both your responses I have a much better understanding of what I was doing wrong.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to pass a primitive by reference.  But you could turn it into an object which would then be passed by reference.  i.e. declare ```this.nav={open: true}``` in firstController and then you could pass the object ```nav``` to the ```toggle``` function (which would be by reference) and change the value like ```nav.open=!nav.open```.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Thanks again.  Helps in my understanding.